# How to convert $_GET into a variable?

Tags: php, html, variables, get, global-variables

I have a problem while using `$_GET`.

I have a URL that looks like `http://www.example.com/404.php?uri=xyz`. Now I would like to read out that `$_GET['uri']` and convert it into a variable that will be used for a header function later on.

The code looks like that:

```
$get_uri = $_GET['uri'];
...
if ( empty($_POST['pref_lang']) === false ) {
   header("Location: ../$content/404.php?uri=$get_uri");    
}
```

But for some reason this does not work. When I change the variable `$get_uri` to something like `$get_uri = "123";` it works. When I will echo out `$get_uri = $_GET['uri']` it will echo it out correctly.

It would be great if someone could give me a hint on how to fetch this.

Thanks alot.

Comment: as long as the header call is in the same scope that `$get_uri` is being set you should be good. try changing the header call to print and see what you get

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown.  What have you done to debug this?  Can you `vardump` $get_uri after you assign to it?

Comment: *does not work* is not an adequate problem description. Instead, describe how your code should behave and how it actually behaves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode it properly:

```
header("Location: ../$content/404.php?" . http_build_query(array('uri' => $get_uri)));
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. i will get the following errormessage: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')' ...

Comment: I fixed the typo, it should be `=>` not `->`.

Comment: What do you see if you change `header` to `echo`? It looks like it works for me.

Comment: Undefined index: uri ... on line 2 => what will be $get_uri = $_GET['uri'];

Comment: That's a completely different problem: the caller of this script isn't sending the `uri=` parameter. You need to check `if (isset($_GET['uri'])`

Comment: okay, but even when i test for isset and then setting the variable into the brackets it does not define the variable.

Comment: Of course. If the parameter isn't set, you shouldn't try to use it. You need to do some other default action.

Comment: i thought the parameter is set when it is in the url. so the url will contain the uri but i can not read it out by $_GET? so what do you mean by default action? thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's set if it's in the URL. If it's not set, that means it wasn't in the URL. Your application needs to do something reasonable when the parameter isn't in the URL.

Comment: but it is set in the url. i can see it there. but when i will read it out and echo it, it will be echoed correctly. the problem is that i can not use it again and send this to the next page. if i will use $_POST method to start the header function it wont be used as variable.

Comment: I think we're confusing things. Are you talking about this page, or the page you're redirecting to?

Comment: okay, i have a page with an url. in that url there is a $_GET parameter set called uri for example: ../page.php?uri=xyz on that page i would like to read out xyz, saving this in a variable and using this in the header-function that will be executed when post submit something: ... header("Location ../404.php?uri=xyz") . So when I will echo out $_GET before header function it will echo it correctly. but later on, when using this in the header function, it does not work. So the problem is that the $_GET will not be posted to the next page. it will be promptly empty?

Comment: I don't see how that happen. If `$_GET['uri']` is set when you assign it to `$get_uri`, and you never reassign it, it has to work when you use it in the `header()` call. Check for typos.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late Reply , in my point of view this code should work , could you please check this code and let me know the feed back

```
<?php  
    $domainName=explode("uri=", "http://www.example.com/404.php?uri=xyz");
    echo $get_uri=$domainName[1];
    if ( empty($_POST['pref_lang']) === false ) {
       header("Location: ../$content/404.php?uri=$get_uri");    
    } 
?>
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering, the problem with the code is that uri=xyz is a variable and will be created automatically. So I need to read out by $_GET. thanks.

Comment: can u give little bit clarity i.e., uri  also varies or only after = i.e., xyz only varies  ?

Comment: otherwise we can use like this , this is like gettign the url and then explode , i think it will work  $domainName=explode("uri=", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);